Cannot change input parameters on @RemoteAction
I added a new function to the Apex controller for our Visualforce page with @RemoteAction decorator so that the client Angular app can find it and call it. Like I've done dozens of times.
@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, String> myNewFunction(){
    Map<String, String> myMap = new Map<String, String>();
    //Do some stuff
    return myMap;
}

However, while developing the function it turned out that the function needed an input parameter from the client. No biggie, I've done this before.
@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, String> myNewFunction(String fieldType){
    Map<String, String> myMap = new Map<String, String>();
    //Do some stuff
    return myMap;
}

But now I was running into a problem.
When I tried to reload the web page I got a Service Unavailable error page.
This was happening before any of my client-side Javascript even had a chance to load. This was failing inside Salesforce before it even fed an HTML page to the client browser.
After some digging and debugging, it turned out that the error was coming from Salesforce's CDN.
Further poking around found this:
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.add(new $VFRM.RemotingProviderImpl({
    "vf": {
        "vid": "066XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        ...
    },
    "actions": {
        "My_Controller_Class": {
            "ms": [
                ...
                {
                    "name": "myNewFunction",
                    "len": 0,
                    "ns": "",
                    "ver": 58.0,
                    "csrf": "...",
                    "authorization": "..."
                },
                ....

The Visualforce compiler (or whatever they call it) added that function and its expected parameter array length to its list of Javascript functions on the page.
Fine, that's how it's supposed to work.
But now, if I changed the parameter array length in the server side Apex class (read: adding an input parameter) then the Javascript function in the list of remote actions could not find an associated backend function and threw an error. Even if I wasn't even trying to call that function from the client web page. The mere existence of a Javascript function on the page without a corresponding server side Apex function made it shit the bed.
Fine. So I just need to change the way the function appears on the page.
Only, that appears to be impossible.
Even removing the controller class from the page didn't do it.
I ended up with a workaround:
I created a new function with a new name that accepts the correct number of parameters. And my code just ignores that function that does nothing.
@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, String> myNewFunction(){
    return null;
}

@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, String> myNewFunctionWithParam(String fieldType){
    Map<String, String> myMap = new Map<String, String>();
    //Do some stuff
    return myMap;
}

It works and it's fine. But this still bothers me from a completionist point of view.
So, how can I remove a function from the Visualforce remoting manager's list of functions?
